Dummy control with unsupport mode
It's my first attempt to write a control programme based on protocol, if anyone has experience with dummy control or robot control please help me ......
My understanding is that before controlling dummy, all signals need to be sent to Header later for pretension.

But in my attempts dummy can't even go into idle mode as it is often in 0x02 unsupport mode. I don't understand how this happens, because when I try to use the software provided by the vendor, dummy of course works fine and in any position.
# Function to pretension the Dummy (first sets Dummy to Idle mode)
def pretension_dummy(sock):
    # Step 1: Set the Dummy to Idle mode
    if not set_dummy_mode(sock, MODE_IDLE):  # 0x01 represents Idle Mode
        logging.error("Could not set Dummy to Idle mode. Aborting Pretension.")
        return False
    
    # Step 2: Once Dummy is in Idle mode, send the Pretension command
    logging.info("Sending Pretension command...")
    response = send_command(sock, COMMAND_PRETENSION, include_crc=True)
    if response and response['message_type'] == COMMAND_PRETENSION:
        logging.info(f"Pretension command successful. Response: {response}")
        messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Pretension command successful.")
        return True
    else:
        logging.error("Failed to send Pretension command.")
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Failed to send Pretension command.")
        return False

# Function to set the Dummy mode (e.g., Idle Mode or Sleep Mode)
def set_dummy_mode(sock, mode):
    if not sock:
        logging.error("No valid socket connection. Cannot set Dummy mode.")
        show_error_message("Connection not established. Please connect first.")
        return False

    logging.info(f"Setting Dummy mode to {mode}...")
    payload = struct.pack('!B', mode)  # Mode value as 1 byte
    response = send_command(sock, SET_MODE, payload, include_crc=True)
    if response and response['message_type'] == SET_MODE:
        logging.info(f"Dummy mode set to {mode}. Response: {response}")
        return True
    else:
        logging.error("Failed to set Dummy mode.")
        show_error_message("Failed to set Dummy mode.")
        return False

I have wrote some code to simulate the pretension, but i always get the error massage is

Maybe there is something wrong with my programming mindset, do you guys have a more sensible way of thinking about the dummy so I can have control over it.
For example, I need to make sure that dummy can go into idle mode, or is there any way to bypass the unsupport mode detection and just start going into working mode.

please do not post images of text
